# how can i saved more than one check box on one column

Tags: php

i have this code :

```
<table width="100%" border="0" id="SpecialReq1"> 
  <tr>   
    <td width="100px"><input type="checkbox" name="txtSpecialReq" id="txtSpecialReq" value="Non-Smookong" class="checkox">Non-Smookong</td>
    <td width="100px"><input type="checkbox" name="txtSpecialReq" id="txtSpecialReq" value="Smooking-Room" class="checkox">Smooking Room</td>
    <td width="100px"><input type="checkbox" name="txtSpecialReq" id="txtSpecialReq" value="Quiet-Room" class="checkox">Quiet Room</td>
    <td width="100px"><input type="checkbox" name="txtSpecialReq" id="txtSpecialReq" value="Parking" class="checkox">Parking</td>
    <td width="100px"><input type="checkbox" name="txtSpecialReq" id="txtSpecialReq" value="Early-Arrival" class="checkox">Early Arrival</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this code to check which i need to save on table , my problem is i canot save more than one check box on one record , so i need to save more than one on on column on table on database, and how can i display it ??

Answer (score 2):

Change the name to `name="txtSpecialReq[]"` on each checkbox.

Then once you submit the form the items will be in an array as `$_POST[txtSpecialReq]`.

```
// output all items in the array
foreach($_POST['txtSpecialReq'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: thankx but how can i add this on table, how can use it on my query

Comment: i am try to use this
`<?php 

include 'config.php'; 

if ($_POST['chkbx']){ 
  $values = implode(',', $_POST['chkbx']); 
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test`(`name`) VALUES('$values')"); 
  if ($query) echo "Done"; 
} 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `test` WHERE `id` = 23"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
$row = $row['name']; 

?>`
but i sent it by ajax to other page and request only one record why ?!!